# Razer keyboard Super keys not working in Linux / X windows

Tags: keyboard

I have a Razer Cynosa V2 and use Ubuntu 20.10. For some reason my Super keys aren't working. I tried using xev in order to see if they were even registering and they aren't. Makes me wonder if there is a kernel driver issue for this keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

The Cynosa V2 and other Razer keyboards have a game mode in which those specific keys are disabled.  You probably triggered game mode on the keyboard. On the Cynosa you can toggle this mode with [Fn + F10]